# How to save multiple rows to my SQL by R shiny

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, server

How to save multiple rows of data in MySQL server from R Shiny? The following codes are only applicable for a single row:

```
saveData <- function(data ) { 

db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = "my_servername", host = options()$mysql$host, 
                  port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
                  password = options()$mysql$password)
query <- sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ('%s')",
    "my_Table", 
    paste(names(data), collapse = ", "),
    paste(data, collapse = "', '")
  )
  dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

Looking for a help from expert. Thanks